# Using xpath in Javascript to read metadata Language of an XML file originally exported from PDF

Tags: javascript, xml, pdf, accessibility, acrobat

Does anyone know what metadata in an XML file would have the language attribute set by Adobe Acrobat in the PDF file from which the XML file was exported? I *know* that a document level Language was set in the PDF, because I did it myself and checked in the Acrobat Properties for the PDF.

But after exporting from PDF to XML (using Acrobat Export To...) the only "document wide" language specification I see is "x-default" (rather than "en-us") in the dc:title element in the metadata. In the body of the document I do see "EN-US" specified for the `<H1>` and for 2 `<P>` elements. (See XML below.)

I am working in Javascript, by the way, using XPath. I was looking to locate the document-wide language, not search through various elements like headings and paragraphs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Created from PDF via Acrobat SaveAsXML -->
<!-- Mapping Table version: 28-February-2003 -->
<TaggedPDF-doc>
<?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c015 84.159810, 2016/09/10-02:41:30        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
                  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
            xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
            xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
            xmlns:pdfuaid="http://www.aiim.org/pdfua/ns/id/"
            xmlns:pdfaExtension="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/extension/"
            xmlns:pdfaSchema="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/schema#"
            xmlns:pdfaProperty="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/property#">
         <dc:format>xml</dc:format>
         <dc:creator>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>Example</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </dc:creator>
         **<dc:title>
            <rdf:Alt>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">LIFE'S MEANING IS 42</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
         </dc:title>**
         <xmp:CreatorTool>Microsoft Word</xmp:CreatorTool>
         <xmp:CreateDate>2017-02-23T00:54:03Z</xmp:CreateDate>
         <xmp:ModifyDate>2017-11-29T22:18:30-05:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
         <xmp:MetadataDate>2017-11-29T22:18:30-05:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
         <xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:2174297D-1BFC-4214-98BF-073A968712F1</xmpMM:DocumentID>
         <xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:77118f50-e6e9-4e1e-a5b3-e7d51d6f16fc</xmpMM:InstanceID>
         <pdf:Producer>Acrobat PDFMaker 15 for Word</pdf:Producer>
         <pdfuaid:part>1</pdfuaid:part>
         <pdfaExtension:schemas>
            <rdf:Bag>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/</pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>
                  <pdfaSchema:prefix>pdf</pdfaSchema:prefix>
                  <pdfaSchema:schema>Adobe PDF Schema</pdfaSchema:schema>
                  <pdfaSchema:property>
                     <rdf:Seq>
                        <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                           <pdfaProperty:category>internal</pdfaProperty:category>
                           <pdfaProperty:description>A name object indicating whether the document has been modified to include trapping information</pdfaProperty:description>
                           <pdfaProperty:name>Trapped</pdfaProperty:name>
                           <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                        </rdf:li>
                     </rdf:Seq>
                  </pdfaSchema:property>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/</pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>
                  <pdfaSchema:prefix>xmpMM</pdfaSchema:prefix>
                  <pdfaSchema:schema>XMP Media Management Schema</pdfaSchema:schema>
                  <pdfaSchema:property>
                     <rdf:Seq>
                        <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                           <pdfaProperty:category>internal</pdfaProperty:category>
                           <pdfaProperty:description>UUID based identifier for specific incarnation of a document</pdfaProperty:description>
                           <pdfaProperty:name>InstanceID</pdfaProperty:name>
                           <pdfaProperty:valueType>URI</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                        </rdf:li>
                        <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                           <pdfaProperty:category>internal</pdfaProperty:category>
                           <pdfaProperty:description>The common identifier for all versions and renditions of a document.</pdfaProperty:description>
                           <pdfaProperty:name>OriginalDocumentID</pdfaProperty:name>
                           <pdfaProperty:valueType>URI</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                        </rdf:li>
                     </rdf:Seq>
                  </pdfaSchema:property>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>http://www.aiim.org/pdfua/ns/id/</pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>
                  <pdfaSchema:prefix>pdfuaid</pdfaSchema:prefix>
                  <pdfaSchema:schema>PDF/UA ID Schema</pdfaSchema:schema>
                  <pdfaSchema:property>
                     <rdf:Seq>
                        <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                           <pdfaProperty:category>internal</pdfaProperty:category>
                           <pdfaProperty:description>Part of PDF/UA standard</pdfaProperty:description>
                           <pdfaProperty:name>part</pdfaProperty:name>
                           <pdfaProperty:valueType>Integer</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                        </rdf:li>
                     </rdf:Seq>
                  </pdfaSchema:property>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
         </pdfaExtension:schemas>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
                           
<?xpacket end="w"?>
<?xpacket end='r'?>
<bookmark-tree>
<bookmark title="This is a heading for the Document">
<destination structID="LinkTarget_22"/>
</bookmark>
</bookmark-tree>

<Document>
<H1 id="LinkTarget_22" xml:lang="EN-US">This is a heading for the Document </H1>

<P xml:lang="EN-US">This is a little bit of text </P>
<Figure Alt="VO Utility User INterface">

<ImageData src="images/TestforPDFCheck4_img_0.jpg"/>
</Figure>

<P xml:lang="EN-US">Here is an image without ALT text: </P>

<Artifact></Artifact>
</Document>
</TaggedPDF-doc>
```

Comment: Don't forget to code-escape (single backticks) inline XML tags in your text, otherwise Markdown will "eat" them.  I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [xml:lang in XML document schemas](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-when-xmllang) it would be possible to apply `xml:lang="EN-US"` at the `<Document>` level. The page explicitly states that the attribute has scope and can be overridden in sub-elements.

It appears Adobe chose not to do that. Looking in [Tagged PDF Best Practice Guide](https://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/TaggedPDFBestPracticeGuideSyntax.pdf) section 5.5.1 talks about the use of the `lang=` attribute.  The default language for a document is in the document's catalog dictionary.

Comment: First off, thank you, Jim, for your help and suggestion about adding backticks.
From what you are saying, it seems that my code will have to be pretty complicated to determine what the overall document language is -- since each PDF-to-XML generator might implement a different solution, I mean put the xml:lang value where it chooses to. Is that really so? As far as you know, does PDF/UA really not care as long as it is specified somewhere?